# Magento or Prestashop DB foreign connection

Tags: php, database, magento, prestashop

I have a client that has a very big real shop.
Now he want an online shop. And want to synchronize the real shop with the online shop.

Firstly I though on a custom development.
But my client also asked for a second budget of prestashop and other more of magento.

For do the development with one of these CMS I think would be necessary one connector, to connect the database of real shop with the database of the online shop.

Exists modules that connect magento/prestashop with other database to obtein the products and the rest?
Is necessary to use an ERP?

If exist the modules or is necessary an ERP, can somebody give me a links to find them?

Answer (score 1):

If you do stick with Magento, I highly recommend the HO Import module. It is extremely easy to use, just build a module with the necessary configurations. It supports a lot of use cases and is much faster than the regular Magento import and the data flow import. From the Github:

> ### Use Cases
>
> Multiple sources per product
>
> One time product / category imports from an old datasource
>
> Periodic category import with values for multiple store views
>
> 15 minute inventory only updates
>
> Nightly complete inventory updates
>
> Nightly price updates
>
> Incremental category/product updates from ERP systems
>
> Customer import
>
> Customer import with billing and shipping address

[Here's a link to the module and it's documentation](https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import)

At my work we use this module all the time because it is the fastest and most robust module for importing, at least that we've used. As long as you can set up a direct connection (via SOAP or REST) or set up an FTP bucket that your module's configuration can grab .csv or .txt files, you will be able to keep your Magento store in sync with any other store you need.

You will need to write your own module that uses the HO Import module. Your module is essentially the configuration for the import that you are setting up, then HO Import reads your configuration and performs the import as often as you'd like.